No such table error when using a SQLite DB in Flutterflow
I'm developing an android app using Flutterflow. The app is supposed to scan SMSs and extracts pieces of information from them and place it in a SQLite DB. I have a button that is linked to the below custom action:
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
// Imports other custom actions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

// Import necessary packages
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sms_inbox/flutter_sms_inbox.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

// Generate MD5 hash from a string
String generateMd5(String input) {
  return md5.convert(utf8.encode(input)).toString();
}

Future<bool> fetchAndSaveSms(BuildContext context) async {
  // Request SMS permission
  var permission = await Permission.sms.status;
  if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    permission = await Permission.sms.request();
    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      print('SMS permission denied');
      return false; // Scanning not complete
    }
  }

  // Initialize SQLite database and table
  final Future<Database> database = openDatabase(
    'MONEY.db',
    version: 1,
  );

  // Fetch SMS messages from "COMBANK"
  SmsQuery query = SmsQuery();
  List<SmsMessage> messages = await query.querySms(
    kinds: [SmsQueryKind.inbox], // Fetch only inbox messages
    address: 'COMBANK', // Filter messages from "COMBANK"
  );

  // Limit to the first 10 messages
  messages = messages.take(10).toList();

  // Save filtered messages to SQLite
  for (SmsMessage message in messages) {
    if (message.sender?.contains('COMBANK') ?? false) {
      // Extract sender (phone number or name)
      String sender = message.sender ?? 'Unknown sender';

      // Extract numerical values from body
      String numericBody =
          message.body?.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), '') ?? '';

      // Get current timestamp
      String timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

      // Calculate MD5 hash (with timestamp)
      String md5Hash = generateMd5('$sender$numericBody$timestamp');

      // Format the DateTime object to "yyyy/MM/dd" for display purposes
      String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd').format(DateTime.now());

      // Add message to SQLite with MD5 hash as message ID
      final db = await database;
      await db.insert(
        'AllMessages',
        {
          'MessageID': md5Hash,
          'MessageTime': formattedDate,
          'MessageSender': sender,
          'MessageBody': message.body ?? 'No body',
        },
      );
    }
  }

  // Set the scanning completion flag
  bool isScanningComplete = true;

  // Return the flag to indicate scanning completion
  return isScanningComplete;
}


However, I get the following error when I run the app on the local flutterflow windows app using my mobile device and also the same error pops up if i download the code and run it using VSCode on an emulator.
Device Log messages when running on local flutterflow app
This is the error i see on vscode -
Exception has occurred.
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(no such table: AllMessages (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO AllMessages (MessageID, MessageTime, MessageSender, MessageBody) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)) sql 'INSERT INTO AllMessages (MessageID, MessageTime, MessageSender, MessageBody) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' args [db0a847fa4b26ce2f6837eadc4c15dba, 2024/05/27, COMBANK, ANOTHER TEST])

I can confirm that the database has the said table intact as I have opened it using a DB browser as shown below.
DB with tables
This is my main.dart code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/url_strategy.dart';
import '/backend/sqlite/sqlite_manager.dart';
import 'backend/firebase/firebase_config.dart';
import 'flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import 'flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import 'flutter_flow/nav/nav.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  GoRouter.optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs = true;
  usePathUrlStrategy();
  await initFirebase();

  await SQLiteManager.initialize();
  await FlutterFlowTheme.initialize();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();

  static _MyAppState of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>()!;
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ThemeMode _themeMode = FlutterFlowTheme.themeMode;

  late AppStateNotifier _appStateNotifier;
  late GoRouter _router;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _appStateNotifier = AppStateNotifier.instance;
    _router = createRouter(_appStateNotifier);
  }

  void setThemeMode(ThemeMode mode) => setState(() {
        _themeMode = mode;
        FlutterFlowTheme.saveThemeMode(mode);
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Mon-EX',
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en', '')],
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        useMaterial3: false,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        useMaterial3: false,
      ),
      themeMode: _themeMode,
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}


I am unable to push the contents of the text messages into the SQLite DB due to this error. Some insight on this would be much much appreciated. (I'm a total newbie btw)
I am able to use simple get and update queries to save and display data from the DB on the same app using text fields and buttons.
When testing I have tried deleting storage and uninstalling the app before testing with no effect.
I have cleared browser cookies (even though SQLite is not supported by the web version, just to make sure the DB upload or queries were not corrupt or had issues)
I've tried chatGPT which says that I should try to create the Table if it is not found in the DB.
Even when i change the name of the DB, the error i get is the Table is not found. Which means the DB itself may not be found by the code?

Since you specify no path to the database, how do you know that openDatabase('MONEY.db, ... opens the database at specific location that you expect? If the file doesn't exist openDatabase just creates an empty one I guess. Use databaseExists to check whether the database exists. Also prefer using fully qualified paths.

Thank you for the insight. Since i'm using flutterflow, i do not know exactly the location of the DB. However, when i downloaded the code and open through vscode, it is located in "assets/sqlite_db_files/" which i think is NOT where i should be directing my code to because I just ran into an error with that path on the flutterflow app.
I used databaseExists and it says no database found :(

Android assets are read-only static resources of your application and there's no way to access them using a path or a URI. If the asset is a prototype of your database, you have to copy it to app's internal storage and open it from there.
